# Compiler running out of memory with polymorphically recursive function

Tags: recursion, elm

If I try to compile the following code for adding to a fingertree, the elm compiler waits a long time and then reports that it is out of memory.

```
module FingerTree exposing(..) 
type Node a
  = Node2 a a
  | Node3 a a a

type Finger a
  = One a
  | Two a a
  | Three a a a
  | Four a a a a

type FingerTree a
  =Empty
  |Single a
  |Deep (Finger a) (FingerTree(Node a)) (Finger a)

fLeftAdd: a -> Finger a -> Finger a
fLeftAdd a0 finger =
  case finger of
    One a1 -> Two a0 a1
    Two a1 a2 -> Three a0 a1 a2
    Three a1 a2 a3 -> Four a0 a1 a2 a3
    Four  a1 a2 a3 a4 -> finger

leftAdd: a -> FingerTree a -> FingerTree a
leftAdd a0 fingerTree=
  case fingerTree of
    Empty -> Single a0
    Single a1 -> Deep (One a0) Empty (One a1)
    Deep left middle right ->
      case left of
        Four a1 a2 a3 a4 ->
          Deep(Two a0 a1) ( leftAdd (Node3 a2 a3 a4) middle) right
        _ -> Deep (fLeftAdd left a0) middle right
```

My first thought was that perhaps you just can't have polymorphic recursion (a polymorphic function calling itself with a different type signature). However this variant, replacing the custom "Finger" and "Node" types with lists, compiles fine:

```
module HackyTree exposing(..)
type HackyTree a
  = Empty
    |Single a
    |Deep (List a) (HackyTree (List a)) (List a)

leftAdd: a -> HackyTree a -> HackyTree a
leftAdd a0 tree=
   case tree of
    Empty -> Single a0
    Single a1 -> Deep [a0] Empty [a1]
    Deep left middle right ->
      case left of
         [a1, a2, a3, a4] ->
             Deep [a0, a1] ( leftAdd [a2, a3, a4] middle) right
         _ -> Deep (a0::left) middle right
```

I'd like to get the first version working. Is this a compiler bug? Is there a recommended way to refactor to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your last line is `_ -> Deep (fLeftAdd left a0) middle right` and not `_ -> Deep (fLeftAdd a0 left) middle right`? If I change it everything compiles fine.

Note that the signature of `fLeftAdd` is `fLeftAdd: a -> Finger a -> Finger a`. You are pattern matching on a `FingerTree a`, in particular the `Deep (Finger a) (FingerTree(Node a)) (Finger a)` case.

With  `_ -> Deep (fLeftAdd left a0) middle right` you're applying `fLeftAdd` to a `left`, which is a `Finger a` and to `a0`, which is an `a`.
You also have the constraint that the result of `(fLeftAdd left a0)` and `right` have the same type.

This means that `(fLeftAdd left a0)` should produce a `Finger a` when given a `Finger a` and an `a` as parameters, which breaks type inference since `fLeftAdd: a -> Finger a -> Finger a`.

This is a minimal example where the compiler doesn't go out of memory:

```
leftAdd: a -> FingerTree a -> FingerTree a
leftAdd a0 fingerTree=
  case fingerTree of
    Deep left middle right ->
      Deep (fLeftAdd left a0) middle right
    _ -> Single a0
```

I pasted it in [Try Elm](http://elm-lang.org/try) and I got the following error messages:

> -- TYPE MISMATCH ---------------------------------------------------------------
>
> The type annotation for `leftAdd` does not match its definition.
>
> 27| leftAdd: a -> FingerTree a -> FingerTree a
>                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ The type annotation is saying:
>
> ```
> a -> FingerTree a -> FingerTree a
> ```
>
> But I am inferring that the definition has this type:
>
> ```
> Finger ? -> FingerTree ? -> FingerTree (Finger ?)
> ```
>
> Hint: A type annotation is too generic. You can probably just switch
>   to the type I inferred. These issues can be subtle though, so read
>   more about it.
>   https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.17.0/hints/type-annotations.md
>
> -- INFINITE TYPE ---------------------------------------------------------------
>
> I am inferring a weird self-referential type for `left`
>
> 30|     Deep left middle right ->
>                ^^^^ Here is my best effort at writing down the type. You will see ? and ∞ for parts of the type that repeat something already
>   printed out infinitely.
>
> ```
> ?
> ```
>
> Usually staring at the type is not so helpful in these cases, so
>   definitely read the debugging hints for ideas on how to figure this
>   out:
>   https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/blob/0.17.0/hints/infinite-type.md

I'd recommend you to try to create a [simple self contained compilable example](http://sscce.org/) and raise an issue on the [compiler project](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler)

Comment: Yep. That's got it. Just a dumb typo. Thanks!